# Convert php datetime to string result in sql

Tags: php, sql-server

The program shows the sql tables in a table in a php page.

Query, with 25 columns:

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM table";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt);
```

Putting it in a table, 25 times, until it reaches the date:

```
   <?php echo $result["Date"]  ;?>
```

Error when displayed in table:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in filepath/table.php on line 73
```

How do I convert datetime to string?

Comment: Can't help you unless you show your code

Comment: We especially need to see line 73 in table.php

Comment: Try googling it, first result would have turned this up http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: You need to show more code. *Where* is `$result` populated? I know your database isn't going to return a PHP DateTime object so you must have done that yourself.

Comment: Instead of select * you could select each column and use convert(varchar(10),<datetime column>,110) as [Column Name]. (change 110 to whatever format you need). You should only select the columns you need anyway especially if the table may add additional columns that you don't need in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If `$result["Date"]` is an instance of \DateTime, you must use `format()` method.

```
echo $result["Date"]->format('Y-m-d');
```